Is there a way to get access tokens for using drive api when I use credential manager and get the google id token?
I am using credential manager for my app where I get the googleID but I need to add scopes for drive api and also need to get an access token. How to I add scopes and get an access token ?
This is my code -
suspend fun saveGoogleCredentials(context: Context,nonce: String): Pair<CredentialManagerExceptions?, GoogleIdTokenCredential?> {
    if (!this::serverClientID.isInitialized) {
        return Pair(
            CredentialManagerExceptions(
                code = 503,
                message = "Google client is not initialized yet",
                details = "Check if Google credentials is provided"
            ), null
        )
    }

    val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setNonce(nonce)
        .setServerClientId(serverClientID)
        .build()

    val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()

    Log.d("CredentialManager", "$request")
    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
        request = request,
        context = context,
    )

    when (val credential = result.credential) {
        is CustomCredential -> {
            if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                return try {
                    // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
                    // authenticate on your server.
                    val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                        .createFrom(credential.data)
                    Pair(null, googleIdTokenCredential)
                } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                    Pair(
                        CredentialManagerExceptions(
                            code = 501,
                            message = "Received an invalid google id token response",
                            details = e.localizedMessage,
                        ), null
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Pair(
        CredentialManagerExceptions(
            code = 502,
            message = "Invalid request",
            details = null
        ), null
    )
}


You can't. Credential Manager supports authentication, not authorization. See this link for authorization: https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android
